# React Pass props to children with PokeApi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-props

I building small React App with [PokeApi](https://pokeapi.co/). So, I want to creating Pokedex App. My problem is that `pokemon.name` doesnt display on screen. I will show you.
So, when I clicked on pokeCard, in SelectedPokemon props saved id of clicked pokeCard.
But, I dont know why,when I doing fetch and passing pokemon props, in children's props I see only array of pages of pokemons instead `pokemon.name`.

[image: pokedex index]

.

Its code of Parent component. I think, that problem may be in fetch.

**Parent component**

```
function About(props) {
  let { SelectedPokemon } = props;
  const [Pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let endpointForPokemonDetails = `${API_URL}${SelectedPokemon}`;
    fetchPokemonDetails(endpointForPokemonDetails);
  });

  const fetchPokemonDetails = (endpointForPokemonDetails) => {
    fetch(endpointForPokemonDetails)
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setPokemon([...Pokemon, result]);
      }, setLoading(false))
      .catch((error) => console.log("Error:", error));
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "fixed",
        top: 150,
        right: 150,
      }}
    >
      <PokemonDetails pokemon={Pokemon} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Its **Children Component**:

```
function PokemonDetails(props) {
  let { pokemon } = props;
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid #333", height: "300px", width: "250px" }}>
      {pokemon.name}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `Pokemon` is array, then in your child component `PokemonDetails`, you need to loop over it.

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal I'm not sure, but I did it like `{pokemon.map((pokemon) => (
          <div key={pokemon.id}>{pokemon.name}</div>
        ))}` . And it works, but wrong. It displaying unlimited array of same pokemon.names. If you need a screenshot, I can attach.

Comment: when you are fetching the pokemon details, is it an array or object?

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal An array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

My `Pokemon` is array. So I to loop over it.

```
{pokemon.map((pokemon) => ( <div key={pokemon.id}>{pokemon.name}</div> ))}
```

When I setting `setPokemon([...Pokemon, result])` means implementation as new collection.
I set `setPokemon([...Pokemon, result])` and all works.